# OutputStreamWriter write()

Tags: java, outputstream

i wrote a small programm for keeping track of method call-back of inputstream and outputstream.

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class TracingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
private String key;
private Writer log;

public TracingOutputStream(OutputStream sink, String key, OutputStream log) {
    super(sink);
    this.key = key;
    this.log = new OutputStreamWriter(log);
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    log.write(key + " write (byte [" + b.length + "])");
    log.write(114);
    super.write(b);
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    log.write(key + " write (byte [" + b.length + "]" + " ," + off + len + ")");
    super.write(b, off, len);
}

@Override
public void flush() throws IOException {
    log.write(key + "flush()");
    super.flush();
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    log.write(key + "close()");
    super.close();
}
```

}

But when i tried main class TracingOutputStreamMain to run, nothing was written. Could anybody explain it for me

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TracingOutputStreamMain {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("log.txt");
        TracingOutputStream tracingOutput = new TracingOutputStream(bytesOutput, "ByteArray", fout);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(tracingOutput);
            TracingOutputStream tracingBufferedOutput = new TracingOutputStream(bufferedOutput, "Buffered", fout)) {
            for(String arg: args)
                tracingBufferedOutput.write(arg.getBytes());
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytesOutput.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than the fact you're posted code that wouldn't even compile? No.

Comment: I have it compiled, but nothing was happend. the log.write() was called but it cannot write anything out "log.txt"

Comment: Your main method never closes nor flushes any stream/writer.

Comment: In java7, a declaration try-with-resource requires not any close and flush method. It be called ARM - automatic resource management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OutputStreamWriter used in TracingOutputStream is never closed. Close it, and the output will suddenly appear in the output file.